# Fully text search with regex in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created one table as below.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id integer,
    info text
);
```

Which contains following data in info column.

```
duration: 4.334 ms
duration: 3.624 ms
duration: 7.721 ms
duration: 4.235 ms
duration: 6.938 ms
duration: 2.135 ms
duration: 9.230 ms
duration: 10.534 ms
```

I want only to extract the milliseconds information. Like 4.334, 3.624 etc.
With below select statement i am able to extract the details.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(info from '^duration:\s+[0-9\.]+\s+ms\s*') FROM '[0-9\.]+') 
FROM my_table;
```

How can I achieve through fully text search? TSVector and TSSearch ?

Comment: As you just want the numbers I don't think full text search would be of any help.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be search for an item based on its duration? Maybe an [expression-based index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html) would be useful?

Comment: Yes, I want the number from the above text. Can we apply the regex on full text search ? Is there any other way to extract the number from above text for optimized way ? I have millions of rows in table and if i apply the above mentioned query then performance is very slow. So i mean regex is slow in performce so i want to do with FTS. Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry : I've misunderstood your question. This answer is unrelevant since it has nothing to do with full text search.

It might be deleted.

If the strings are all the same (i.e only the values change), you can play with the string functions left & right :

```
select id, left(right(info, -10), -3)
from my_table
```

`left (a, 2)` takes the first 2 chars of a.

`left (a, -2)` takes all but the first 2 chars of a.